# Postgres date_trunc() time zone problem in R with DBI and RPostgres packages

Tags: r, postgresql, rstudio

I am using "RPostgres" and "DBI" packages in RStudio to extract data from Postgres database. UTC is the default time zone in the database.

Here is the problem I encountered. From my perspective,these two queries should have the same output which should be "2018-10-01" (America/Los_Angeles time zone). However, the second one seems to be a result converted from "2018-10-01" (UTC time zone).

```
> dbGetQuery(con,"select date_trunc('month',(current_timestamp at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles')::date - interval '1 day')")
  date_trunc
1 2018-10-01

> dbGetQuery(con,"select date_trunc('month',(current_timestamp at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles')::date)")
       date_trunc
1 2018-09-30 17:00:00
```

I am wondering how date_trunc() works in my case. Did I do something wrong? My goal is to generate the first day of a given month based on "America/Los_Angeles" time zone.

Thanks!

Comment: LA time is GMT-7h. Notice that `2018-09-30 17:00:00 +7h == 2018-10-01`?
The issue could either be rounding back to GMT during the ::DATE cast (within the query), could be similar casting due to the ` - interval '1 day'` part, or could potentially be caused during the 'printing' phase (e.g. maybe the `-interval '1 day'` changes the class so it is printed as a datetime instead of a date). Fiddle with your system until you work it out.